# ¿Cómo envío el valor de una celda de un datagrid que contiene una fecha a un DataTimePicker de C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo un DateTimePicker donde selecciono una fecha que es guardada y posteriormente mostrada en un DataGridView.

Lo que quiero es que, al seleccionar la celda con la fecha guardada, aparezca en el DateTimePicker.

Lo que estoy ocupando es el evento del data grid siguiente:

```cs
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{ 
    DataGridViewRow dgv = dataGUsuarios.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    txtIDUsuario.Text = dgv.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    TxtContraseña.Text = dgv.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    ValorTipoUsuario = dgv.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    txtNombresUsuarios.Text = dgv.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    txtApellidosUsuario.Text = dgv.Cells[5].Value.ToString();

    //dataTFNacimiento = dgv.Cells[6].Value.();

    txtNumeroUsuario.Text = dgv.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    txtCorreoUsuario.Text = dgv.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
    rtxtRedSocialUsuario.Text = dgv.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
    rtxtDireccionUsuario.Text = dgv.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
}
```

La línea de código comentada es la que no sé cómo formular.

Answer (score 3):

Suponiendo que `dataTFNacimiento` es tu `DateTimePicker`, hace falta convertir `dgv.Cells[6].Value` al tipo de `dataTFNacimiento.Value` y asignárselo. Imagino que estará en formato fecha o string. Puedes probar directamente este código que debería funcionarte:

```
dataTFNacimiento.Value = DateTime.Parse(dgv.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
```

Si no te funciona debes decirnos qué es `dataTFNacimiento` y qué tipo de valor hay en `dgv.Cells[6].Value`.

Answer (score 0):

**Te falto esto**

```
dataTFNacimiento.Value=Convert.ToDateTime(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
```

te falto CurrentRow.cells 
y Convert.To.DateTime